# How to take data from <input> and translate it to JS variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using HTML to create checklists through `<input>`. Here's a small sample of my code.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Expedia" />
<img src="http://cruise360.org/media/ex_logos/3zp4zr1avvnfydluitkn4yur31iveig3172013_111844.jpg" style="width:236px;height:135px;" />
<br />
```

How can I make a javascript variable that is set to 0 or 1 depending on whether the option is checked. For example I'd have something like:

```
if (box is checked..) {
  expediaChecked == 1
} else {
  exediaChecked==0
}
```

How can I connect HTML and Javascript like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```js
function myFunction(cb) {
expediaChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
    console.log(expediaChecked);  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Expedia" onchange="myFunction(this)"><img src="http://cruise360.org/media/ex_logos/3zp4zr1avvnfydluitkn4yur31iveig3172013_111844.jpg" style="width:236px;height:135px;"><br>
```

Comment: If I wanted to change it to say an <h1> and have it change the variables value on click would I keep it the same as `onchange="myFunction(this)` or should I change it to `onclick` and also do I need to change the `cb` in the first part? How should I change it?

Comment: you want checkbox to be replace with h1 ? or you want checkbox inside h1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some way to identify that input. I'd stick an id on there to make it cleaner/faster, but you can use class/tag.

```
if(document.getElementById('expediaBox').checked){
  expediaChecked = 1;
}else{
  expediaChecked = 0;
}
```

I believe you can one line it if you wanted to:

```
expediaChecked = document.getElementById('expediaBox').checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Edit: Apparently you can use document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Expedia"]') in place of the document.getElement if you're using a modern browser.

Comment: Thank you. I think it worked. Question though: when does it work, does the variable change to 1 as soon as I check it?

Comment: No, in order to change the variable on the fly, you'll want to wrap that check into an eventlistener.

Comment: `document.getElementById('expediaBox').addEventListener('change', function(){ //stuff you want to run goes in here});`
for example. webdeb's answer is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Define a onchange handler

```
<input id="expediaBox" type="checkbox" value="Expedia" />

document.getElementById('expediaBox').onchange = function(e) {
  expediaChecked = e.target.checked ? 1 : 0;
  // debug it
  console.log('checkbox checked', expediaChecked);
}
```